# What is role of copper powder, calcium chloride and cuprous chloride in the SN1 reaction of hydrochloric acid with propargylic alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution

For the synthesis of a 2H-cromene from a phenol I need to prepare 3-chloro-2-methyl-but-1-yne from the corresponding alcohol 2-methylbut-3-yn-2-ol. This reaction could be seen as a simple $S_\text N1$ substitution.

**Plausible mechanism:**
[image: plausible mechanism]

However it requires a catalytic amount of copper powder, and almost half equivalent of $\ce{CaCl2}$ and $\ce{CuCl}$, in addition to concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ at 0°C temperature. The authors say that these additives are necessary to avoid the formation of a series of subproducts but they don't talk about mechanistic explanation about the role of these additives.

**Possible subproducts:**
[image: possible subproducts]

In my opinion, the formation of subproducts derived from the eneyne, obtained from dehydration, is suppressed using low temperature.

So the additives act probably on the carbocation. We may suppose the formation of a copper acetilyde that makes the resonance structure of carbocation less important. This is corroborated by the use of concentrated HCl during the work-up. But I don't understand how it is possible to form a copper acetilyde in acid media (usually it requires the presence of a base that deprotonate the alkyne).

The autors says that the formation of subproducts is more evident for propargylic alcohol that have a low solubilty in water (this is not the case of 2-methylbut-3-yn-2-ol).Regarding the presence of $\ce{CaCl2}$, I know that this salt is used in the distillation of some halocompounds because it interacts in some way with alcohol. So maybe $\ce{CaCl2}$ helps the solubilization of alcohol.

Can you please explain the role of each additives?

**Reference:**

G. F. Hennion, A. P. Boisselle, J. Org. Chem. 1961, 26, 725–727.

Answer (score 4):

My take as to the likely role for a catalytic amount of copper powder, $\ce{CaCl2, HCl},$ and $\ce{CuCl}$ is as follows:

$\ce{ Cu + Cu(II) <=> 2 Cu(I) }$

where the $\ce{Cl-}$ presence forms a soluble complex to keep the reaction reversible:

$\ce{ CuCl + Cl-  <=>  CuCl2- }$

The first equation is an example of a working so-called redox couple with an associated presence of solvated electrons $\ce{(e-)}$ in the alcohol medium. Further, in the presence of H+ (from the $\ce{HCl}$), we have:

$\ce{ H+ + e- <=> H^.}$

The formed hydrogen radical can further attack an organic complex resulting in either hydrogen or water with the introduction of an associated organic radical:

$\ce{ RH + H^. <=> ^.R + H2}$

Or:

$\ce{ ROH + ^.H <=> ^.R + H2O}$

At low temperatures, the above reaction is moved to the right. A minor formation reaction is also possible:

$\ce{ R^. + ^.R -> R2 (g)}$

where the above reaction could account for any reported associated formation of a metal acetylide.

Lastly, I suspect, presence of $\ce{CaCl2}$ adds $\ce{Cl-}$ and also removes water and further engages with the alcohol creating an addition compound.

I trust this helps.